# Exclude weekends and public holiday for SQL datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server

this code works but seems like the results are off by 1 day

**Objective:** Find the datediff for the two dates given.

However, we will have to **exclude**

- Weekends
- Public Holiday

**Example**

The difference between 2017-11-04 00:00:00 and 2017-11-22 10:21:00

- Expected Results: 12.42 (Excluded 3 Saturdays & Sundays)
- Current Results: 13.42

The code is not written by me, so i'm trying to understand it. I commented some parts that i am unclear as well.

```
/**This part is to find the difference in time for the two dates**/
DECLARE @temp AS DECIMAL(10,2) = CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, CONVERT(time, @StartDate), CONVERT(time, @ENDDate)) as Decimal(10,2))/24.00


Declare @numdays int=0

/**This part is to find the difference in date for the two dates**/
/**Issues likely to come from here**/
IF DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@ENDDate)>0 
BEGIN
    WHILE DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@ENDDate)>0
    BEGIN 
        SET  @StartDate=DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate) 
        WHILE exists (SELECT Holiday_Date FROM Holiday where Holiday_Date=CONVERT(date, @StartDate))  or DATENAME(DW,@StartDate)='saturday' or DATENAME(DW,@StartDate)='sunday'
            BEGIN
                SET  @StartDate=DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate)
                /**Exclude weekends and PH so we do not add numDays here **/
            END
        SET @numDays=@numDays+1
    END
END

/**Omitted some irrelevant codes here**/

/**Add both differences together to get final result**/
DECLARE @result AS DECIMAL(10,2) = @temp + @numDays

RETURN @result
```

Was thinking to just correct the logic instead of rewriting the entire code. Thanks!

Comment: Best way to do is using calendar table where you can also define local public holidays has the option to exclude if required

Comment: _Which_ public holidays?  Every country is different.

Comment: The values for the public holiday table is assumed correct in this case. The example given does not include any public holiday.

Comment: @JAYY assumed by *whom*? The server has no idea what the developer's assumptions are. Use a calendare table instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like has been mentioned, the best way is to create a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/) and then use the Working Days column, or whatever it is you called it, to calculate the difference.

This is pseudo-SQL, in the absence of a working Calendar Table, but should get you there:

```
SELECT YT.{YourColumn},
       WD.WorkingDays
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(CT.DateKeyColumn) -1 AS WorkingDays --Minus 1, as we don't want to include the first day
                  FROM CalendarTable CT
                  WHERE CT.[DateColumn] >= YT.StartingDateColumn
                    AND CT.[DateColumn] <= YT.EndingDateColumn
                    AND CT.WorkingDay = 1) WD
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you mentioned does essentially the following in pseudocode:

```
while i between @StartDate and @ENDDate
begin
    increment i by 1
    increment i until it is not a holiday
    add one day to result
end
return result
```

My opinion is that this code is ugly and inefficient.

1. It uses @StartDate as both the "input parameter", ie the true
   starting date, AND the loop variable. That is confusing.
2. The use of loops and cursors are efficient in very specific cases, and this certainly is NOT one of them.

90% of the hassle in your kind of question is the creation of the calendar table; but you already have one. Do not use this function; change the code to what Larnu suggests. Ask us further clarification if you encounter difficulty doing so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur answer. But i'm still confused why the code added an extra day. Do you know why?

Comment: Notice how Larnu's code has a count ()-1? This is because the difference between two numbers is the count of all numbers between first and last minus one. Eg: the difference between 4 and 6 is 2: 3 numbers total (4,5,6) but you have to substract 1. This is missing in the function; instead of calculating the difference, it calculates non-holiday days, which is always one more.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in MySQL 5.1:
MySQL's "weekday" function returns 0 for Mon, 5 for SAT and 6 for SUN, thus you see below SQL has some magic no. with 5 and 6.

Sample:

```
select  floor((datediff (ed, st)+1) / 7)*2 /*complete week's weekends*/
        + case when floor((datediff (ed, st) +1) % 7) between 0 and 6 /*additional weekends besides complete weeks*/
                then case when weekday(ed) >= weekday(st) then least(floor((datediff (ed, st) +1) % 7), greatest(least(6, weekday(ed)) - greatest(5, weekday(st)) + 1,0))
                                else least(floor((datediff (ed, st) +1) % 7), greatest(least(6, weekday(ed)+7) - greatest(5, weekday(st)) + 1,0)) end
            else 0
        end as num_of_sat_and_sun
from (select '2019-01-07' as st, '2019-01-12' as ed) x
```